# Etymology of болельщик

Tags: этимология

I had difficulties in finding a translation of *болельщик*,  and it seems to mean (sports) fan, supporter.
Does this word come from a transliteration as *бол* of the English word *ball* ?

Comment: No, it's from болеть like in "болеть за команду".

Comment: I first learned the verb болеть as "to be sick/hurt," e.g., у меня болит нога (my leg hurts). So I always rationalized болеть за команду or болельщик as "being sick" for a team as a metaphorical usage, similar to expressing excessive support in English by words related to being unwell ("he's crazy for that team").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Болеть душой** *о ком- чем* -- проявлять сострадание, скорбеть, заботиться.

So one of the meanings of the word is *to care*. The meaning *to support* (e.g. a sports team) is just around the corner.

Some examples of similar morphology are: *плакальщик*, *курильщик*, *тральщик*, *резчик*, *верстальщик*.

Answer (score 13):

*Болельщик* origins from the construct *болеть (душой) за* .  Examples:

- “Коли-де сам государь-батюшка с топором в своих царских руках, валит
  лес, по пояс в воде, долбней вбивает сваи, как же нам, рабам его, не
  терпеть? Сам-то он **болеет за нас душой**, да, видно, дело-то
  нужное. Не трудил бы, не мучил бы себя, коли б не видал нашей пользы” (1832)
- Исчез лучший и вернейший друг нашего общества. Он любил его
  превыше всего, он жил душою в нем, он мучился, страдал и болел за
  него. (1897)
- Добросовестная работница всей душой болеет за производство, а рядом с нею ― злостная лодырница, только портит материал, форменная вредительница. (1928-1931)

Today "болеть за" is mostly used for sport teams and sportsmen (note than in Russia(n) chess, checkers etc. are also considered sports).  Examples:

- Oн «болел» за «Зубило». (1955)
- Лет восемь назад, в Москве, я ходил на футбол часто, болел за «Спартак» (1959-1962)
- Партийный и чиновничий аппарат активно болел за Карпова. (2009) (It's about the Karpov-Kasparov 1985 chess match.)

There are also rather emotional expressions "болеть за дело", "болеть за страну" etc.

One can also "болеть за" virtually any person, country, etc., especially in a conflict/competition between people or entities. Examples:

- когда ты будешь защищать диплом, я буду болеть за тебя
- Я буду болеть за тебя всей душой,ты справишься!

The expression "болеть душой за" is not used since early 20th century. Sometimes "болеть всей душой" is used, but it is very emotional.

The word "болельщик" is only about sports (including chess etc.)  You cannot be a "болельщик" of a musical band etc.